# Custom shape setting different colors to included geometries wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes, pathgeometry

I created a custom `Shape` constructed from a `Rectangle` and a `Text` inside it. Here is the code:

```
    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            var formattedText = new FormattedText(Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Verdana"), 14, Brushes.Transparent);
            var chosenTextPoint = new Point
            {
                X = ((Location.X < BottomRight.X) ? Location.X : BottomRight.X) + 5,
                Y = ((Location.Y < BottomRight.Y) ? Location.Y : BottomRight.Y) + 5
            };

            Stroke = Brushes.ForestGreen;
            StrokeThickness = (IsSelected) ? HighlightedValue : HighlightedValue / 2;

            Rectangle = new Rect(Location, BottomRight);

            var rectangleGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(Rectangle);
            var textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(chosenTextPoint);

            var combinedGeometry = new CombinedGeometry
            {
                GeometryCombineMode = GeometryCombineMode.Xor,
                Geometry1 = rectangleGeometry,
                Geometry2 = textGeometry
            };

            combinedGeometry.Geometry1.SetValue(FillProperty, Brushes.Blue);
            combinedGeometry.Geometry1.InvalidateProperty(FillProperty);
            Fill = (IsSelected) ? Brushes.Transparent : null;

            return combinedGeometry;
        }
    }
```

The `combinedGeometry` is something I've added recently, before that I used `PathGeometry`. In both cases, both the `Rectangle` and the `Text` are colored in the same color, and "suffer" the same shape-effects.

I there a way to separate between the two? By separating I mean the they will both be individual elements inside the `Shape`, which I can freely modify any of them or both of them all together?

Comment: You can't set the Fill property on a Geometry. A Shape always has a single Fill and a single Stroke. Use two Shapes if you want different Fills/Strokes.

Answer (score 1):

A `Geometry` doesn't have colors - it's just what it name implies. `Shape`s draw a single geometry with fill and stroke brushes.

You can either:

- Use multiple shapes. This can be costly since every `Shape` is a full-fledged control that can accept input, render, etc.
- Use a `Drawing`, which can contain multiple geometries with multiple brushes, and then render it using an `DrawingImage` (a type of `ImageSource`) in an `Image` control or a `DrawingBrush` (a type of `Brush`) as the fill/background of some other control (e.g. a `Rectangle`). Note that Blend (a tool that comes with Visual Studio) can convert a group of controls to a `DrawingBrush` (Tools > Make Brush).
- Create a control from scratch, inheriting from `FrameworkElement` and render it yourself by overriding `OnRender`.